# Pending Documents on a non-existent printer

Tags: printer, uninstall, documents

I had a Lexmark installed on my computer and when I unplugged it and got rid of it, it must have had pending documents so now that I'm trying to uninstall it from my computer it won't let me.  It says the printer is busy and I'll have to wait until it's finished.  I don't know how to pull it up to cancel the docs now, I've tried to access them through DOS and can't figure it out.  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the docs in the queue and restart the spooler.

> **net stop spooler**
>
> **del %systemroot%\System32\spool\printers* /Q**
>
> **net start spooler**

Failing that, open up msconfig and remove any entries related to the printer in both the programs and services section. Restart and try again.